# How do I link my website and YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

How do I link my website and YouTube channel? I know it involves uploading a file on my web server and verifying it from YouTube but I am unable to find the option anywhere in YouTube settings.

Comment: link from where?

Comment: Have you tried the steps listed here? https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2887282?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

To link your website with your YouTube channel, the first criteria is to be part of YouTube Partner Program (YPP). You need to have at least 1,000 subscribers and more than 4,000 valid public watch hours in the last 12 months to be part of YPP.

If you are already part of YPP, you can associate your site with your YouTube account:

1. Sign in to [YouTube Studio](http://studio.youtube.com/).
2. From the left menu, select Settings and then Channel and then [Advanced settings](https://www.youtube.com/advanced_settings?nv=1). Under “Other channel settings”, select Advanced channel settings.
3. In the "Associated website" section, enter your website's URL and click Add. It will show as "pending," unless you've verified the site before.
4. Under the URL box, click verify if you own the website or request approval to have the website's owner approve it. If you select request approval, a notification will be sent to the website owner. If you select verify, you'll be redirected to Google's Search Console. Sign in with the same Google Account information that you use for your YouTube channel. (If you're not sure what account to use, you can check your account details on YouTube.)
5. Choose a method to verify your ownership.
6. Follow the instructions to add a site to Search Console. You may be asked to choose a verification method.

After you add your site to Search Console, it will go through a verification process. Once verification is complete, the website's status will change from "pending" to "success" in your Advanced Channel Settings and you can follow the steps below to add a card that will take viewers to any page in that website.

**Add a card on videos to link to your website**
After you associate your site with your account, you can add a card that links to your website directly on your videos.

1. Sign in to YouTube Studio.
2. From the left menu, select Videos.
3. Next to the video you want to change, click Details , then select Cards.
4. Click Add card.
5. Next to "Link," click Create. The first time you're using external links, you'll need to accept the Terms & Conditions.
6. Under "Associated website," select your website's URL from the Select site drop-down menu. Click Add an associated website or Settings to associate a site.
7. Click Next.
8. Add the card title, call to action, and teaser text. You can also upload an image.
9. Click Create card.

Reference:

1. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851
2. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2887282